# Why does `filter` work with higher-order occurrence typing?

Tags: racket, higher-order-functions, type-theory, typed-racket

On the homepage for Racket, they show this example:

```
#lang typed/racket
;; Using higher-order occurrence typing
(define-type SrN (U String Number))
(: tog ((Listof SrN) -> String))
(define (tog l)
  (apply string-append (filter string? l)))
(tog (list 5 "hello " 1/2 "world" (sqrt -1)))
```

I know that with occurrence typing, an expression like `(if (string? v) ...)` will mark `v` as having type `String` in the true branch.  This is because the type of `string?` has a filter on it:

```
> string?
- : (Any -> Boolean : String)
#<procedure:string?>
```

So, for "higher-order occurrence typing" to work with the `filter` function, I would expect the type of `filter` to say that a filter on the predicate's type gets propagated to the result type. But when I check the type of `filter` in the REPL, this doesn't show up:

```
> filter
- : (All (a b) (case-> ((a -> Any) (Listof a) -> (Listof b)) ((a -> Any) (Listof a) -> (Listof a))))
#<procedure:filter>
```

But this can't be the real type of `filter`, because there's no constraint on `b`!  I expected something like

```
(All (a b) (a -> Any : b) (Listof a) -> (Listof b))
```

tldr: Why does `filter` appear have an unconstrained type variable in its return type?

EDIT: I am using Racket v6.0

Comment: You seem to be using an older version of Racket which doesn't print the extra type filter information on `filter`. If you upgrade you will see the type that Renzo shows in his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [Typed Racket Reference](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/type-ref.html#%28part._.Other_.Type_.Constructors%29) it is said:

> In some cases, asymmetric type information is useful in filters. For example, the `filter` function’s first argument is specified with only a positive filter.
>   Example:

```
> filter
- : (All (a b)
      (case->
       (-> (-> a Any : #:+ b) (Listof a) (Listof b))
       (-> (-> a Any) (Listof a) (Listof a))))
#<procedure:filter>
```

> The use of `#:+` indicates that when the function applied to a variable evaluates to a true value, the given type can be assumed for the variable. However, the type-checker gains no information in branches in which the result is `#f`.

In other words, if you have the following example:

```
> (filter string? '(symbol 1 2 3 "string"))
- : (Listof String)
'("string")
```

the system can says that an element of the list `'(symbol 1 2 3 "string")` is of type `String` only when `string?` returns `true` on it. Only in this case the type of the filter's predicate is propagated.